Example of Conformal but Inhomogeneous configuration
This is probably a beginner-level question in this realm of mathematical physics.
I understand conformality symmetric system as invariant with the conformal transformation, where conformal symmetry involves stretching and distorting of coordinate systems that still maintains the angle. I do not, however, have good intuition when it comes to conformal symmetric systems, except for homogeneous systems; they are obviously conformally symmetric, since under any stretching or distortion of the coordinate system, the function remains a constant, hence, does not change under conformal symmetry. However, I cannot think of functions that are inhomogeneous AND conformally symmetric.
Please give me specific examples of inhomogeneous AND conformally symmetric systems, and if necessary, use equations. Thanks in advance!
